# pymongo float precision

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo, floating-accuracy

I have a number stored in mongo as 15000.245263 with 6 numbers after decimal point but when I use pymongo to get this number I got 15000.24. Is the pymongo reduced the precision of float?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. In Python 2.7.13 on my Mac:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> c = MongoClient().my_db.my_collection
>>> c.delete_many({})  # Delete all documents
>>> c.insert_one({'x': 15000.245263})
>>> c.find_one()
{u'x': 15000.245263, u'_id': ObjectId('59525d32a08bff0800cc72bd')}
```

The retrieved value of "x" is printed the same as it was when I entered it.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you trying to print out a long float value, and i think it is not related to mongodb.

```
>>> print 1111.1111
1111.1111

>>> print 1111111111.111
1111111111.11

>>> print 1111111.11111111111
1111111.11111

# for a timestamp
>>> import time
>>> now = time.time()
>>> print now
1527160240.06
```

For python2.7.10 it will just display 13 character(for my machine), if you want to display the whole value, use a format instead, like this:

```
>>> print '%.6f' % 111111111.111111
111111111.111111
```

And this is just a display problem, the value of the variable will not be affected.

```
>>> test = 111111111.111111 * 2
>>> test
222222222.222222
>>> print test
222222222.222
```